# Java Custom Exception handling with Object and Driver class

Tags: java, object, exception, driver

I am having trouble with my custom book exception to interact with my program that creates a book object and for that too finally interact with my driver class Bookstore.java. My driver class doesn't catch the inconsistencies from happening. Like:

- title should not be blank or contain blanks only
- isbn should be a number between 1000 and 10000 (inclusive)
- quantity should not be negative (zero is ok, it means out of stock)

When I run my driver class BookStore.java, it does not catch the above errors that I have written in book.java.

----------------------------------Creates book Object

```
public class Book{
//instance variables
private String title = "";
private int isbn;
private int quantity;

public Book (String title, int isbn, int quantity)throws BookException{     
//constructors

this.title = title;
this.isbn = isbn;
this.quantity = quantity;

}
public String toString( ){ //toString Method

String s = "";
s = s + "Title: " + this.title + "\nISBN: " + this.isbn
+   "\nQuantity: " + this.quantity + "\n";
return s;

}

public String gettitle( ){
return this.title;
}
public int getisbn( ){
return this.isbn;
}
public int getquantity( ){  
return this.quantity;
}

//mutator methods
public void settitle(String newtitle )throws Exception{
if(newtitle.length()<1){
BookException be = new BookException( );
be.setMessage("Title cannot be blank");
throw be;
}
else{
this.title=newtitle;
}
}

public void setisbn(int newisbn)throws Exception{
if(newisbn>=1000 && newisbn>=10000){
this.isbn = newisbn;
}
else{
BookException be = new BookException( );
be.setMessage("ISBN should be between 1000 and 10000.");
throw be;
}
}

public void setquantity(int newquantity)throws Exception{
if(newquantity>=0){
this.quantity = newquantity;
}
else{
BookException be = new BookException( );
be.setMessage("Quantity can't be a negative number.");
throw be;
}
}

}
```

-----------------------------------------------Custom Book Exception

```
public class BookException extends Exception{
//instance variable
private String message = "";

public BookException( ){
//empty constructor

}
public void setMessage(String newMessage){
this.message = newMessage;
}
public String getMessage( ){
return this.message;
}
}
```

------------------------------------------------------ Driver Class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Bookstore{

//this program will read the information for one book
//it will validate it and print it if correct

public static void main(String arg[ ]) throws Exception{

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int size = 3;
int isbn=0;
int quantity = 0;
String title = "";
int count=0;
boolean exit = false;
Book oneBook;

try{
System.out.print("Enter title: ");
title = sc.nextLine( );
sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println();
System.out.print("Enter isbn: ");
isbn = sc.nextInt( );
sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println();
System.out.print("Enter quantity: ");
quantity = sc.nextInt( );
sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println();
oneBook = new Book(title, isbn, quantity); //attempting to create the book
//if any information about the book is inconsistent the BookExcpetion will be
//thrown by the Book constructor/set methods and it should be caught
System.out.println("The book entered was:");
System.out.println(oneBook.toString( ));
}

catch(InputMismatchException ime){
System.out.println("you did not enter a number");
}
catch (BookException be){
System.out.println(be.getMessage( )); //calling the getMessage from BookException.java
}

} //main method
} //class
```

---

I would really appreciate the help and tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor always passes. Change from

```
this.title = title;
this.isbn = isbn;
this.quantity = quantity;
```

to

```
setTitle(title);
setIsbn(isbn);
setQuantity(quantity);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Book (String title, int isbn, int quantity)throws BookException{     
//constructors

this.title = title;
this.isbn = isbn;
this.quantity = quantity;

}
```

just adding a throws clause there, won't make it so. You'll need to actually throw them too. For instance, if title may not be null or empty:

```
public Book (String title, int isbn, int quantity)throws BookException{     
//constructors

this.title = title;
if ( title == null || title.isEmpty())
  throw new BookException("Please provide a title");
this.isbn = isbn;
this.quantity = quantity;

}
```

Comment: Hmm, I understand your method there. But I also have: 
catch (BookException be){
         System.out.println(be.getMessage( )); 
      }

In my driver class. Which is calling the getMessage from BookException.java  :(

Comment: Asia_x3 : yes, but as long as you don't throw the exception, it can not be caught.

Answer (score 0):

Murat.K already provided an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29938728/1991295) that I am not going to repeat.

I am however going to give some some extra advice. First of all, Java already has an exception that deals with illegal / invalid arguments, and that's called [IllegalArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html#IllegalArgumentException-java.lang.String-). You should really use it and not create your own exception that's supposed to be doing the same thing. Also, note that `IllegalArgumentException` is an [unchecked exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html), meaning you don't need a `throws IllegalArgumentException` in the method signature or in a `catch` block (unless you want to catch it).

If you still want to use your own exception, there's no need for the `message` field and its setter and getter, because the parent `Exception` class already has them (well, except for the setter, but it's not needed, as you set the message in the constructor anyway). So your class should look like this

```
public BookException extends Exception {
    public BookException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

And you can throw it on one line like

```
throw new BookException("some error"); //no need for setter
```