# Constructor Exception not working (Java)

Tags: java, exception

I just needed help regarding my stuff and It seems one had a similar question so I just had to copy/paste it

Although an answer was given, java would error out on the answer that was given on that same area

I am having trouble with my custom book exception to interact with my program that creates a book object and for that too finally interact with my driver class Bookstore.java. My driver class doesn't catch the inconsistencies from happening. Like:

> *title should not be blank or contain blanks only
>   
>   *isbn should be a number between 1000 and 10000 (inclusive)
>   *quantity should not be negative (zero is ok, it means out of stock)

When I run my driver class `BookStore.java`, it does not catch the above errors that I have done through exceptions. 
Here is the same question That I wanted to ask

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938646/java-custom-exception-handling-with-object-and-driver-class)

Seems my bookstore is not taking the exceptions on my book program

Doing the set commands does not work and errors out and using the default one does not show the exceptions that I wanted to from my book program

Comment: Provide us some code please. Without it we could only guessing.

Comment: The code is in the link. It's pretty much the same

Comment: If it exactly the same you can use solution from the link. If this solution doesn't work, that means you have different code.

Comment: I'm certain we have the same i tried changing this:          this.title = title;
this.isbn = isbn;
this.quantity = quantity to the given answer and it says error can't find

Comment: @aldz24 In the answer they have given are not  set commands- they are setter methods for member variables.You need to write that setter methods and do your checking and throw exception in the unexpected scenarios.

Comment: check this code https://github.com/hr6134/sof34039954 it's exactly like in the answer + fixes. BTW this code full of antipatterns and bad practices. So, you could use it as an example for checked exceptions. But better to make Book class immutable + add builder pattern. Also it's better to keep java code style. Think, I'll rewrite it in a good way and republish soon.

Answer (score 0):

The code (with the fix suggested in the answer) does not compile, giving the error message

```
./Book.java:10: error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

This can be fixed by changing the declaration of your setters to throw the exact Exception `BookException` rather than the generic `Exception`.

```
public void settitle(String newtitle )throws BookException{
```